# Creating a Tree from an input string

Tags: java, parsing, tree, generics

I have a tree in a file which looks like this:

```
(1 (2 (3 (10 11) 15) 4 (5 (() 13) 6)))
```

Here, a Node and its children are written like this:

- A `Node` with its left are right `Nodes` - `node (node.left node.right)`
- A `Node` which has an empty left `Node` - `node (() node.right)`
- The `Root Node` is special and is written as `(rootNode (rootNode.left rootNode.right)`

A tree is derived with this BNF form:

```
S -> (E)
E -> E(EE)|()|<numbers>
```

Thus,  `() and (())` are valid trees but `(()())` is not.

---

Now, I want to create a `Tree` with any such inputs. I also wanted to be able to create a `Tree<String>` which might have inputs like:

```
(a (b (also (some ()) there) c))
```

etc.

Here is my `Tree`:

```
package org.yadavvi.util;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Tree<T> {

    public Node<T> root;

    public Tree(Node<T> node) {
        root = node;
    }

    public static <T> int maxDepthOfTree(Tree<T> tree) {
        if (tree == null) return -1;
        if (tree.root == null) return 0;
        int depth = 0;

        List<Node<T>> nodesAtLevel = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Node<T>> nodes = new ArrayList<>();

        nodesAtLevel.add(tree.root);
        nodes.addAll(nodesAtLevel);
        nodesAtLevel.clear();

        while (!nodes.isEmpty()) {
            nodesAtLevel.clear();
            depth++;

            for (Node<T> node : nodes) {
                if (node.left != null) nodesAtLevel.add(node.left);
                if (node.right != null) nodesAtLevel.add(node.right);
            }

            nodes.clear();
            nodes.addAll(nodesAtLevel);
        }
        return depth;
    }

    public static class Node<T> {
        public T value;
        public Node<T> left;
        public Node<T> right;

        public Node(T value) {
            this.value = value;
            left = null;
            right = null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            return value.equals(obj);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return value.hashCode();
        }
    }

}
```

This is the Utility class that I use to create the tree:

```
package org.yadavvi.util;

import org.yadavvi.util.Tree.Node;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Stack;

public class TreeUtil {

    public static <T> Tree<T> createTreeFromFile(String fileName) {
        try (BufferedReader inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
            return createTreeFromString(inputStream.readLine());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static <T> Tree<T> createTreeFromString(String s) {
        return new Tree<>(createTree(s));
    }

    private static <T> Node<T> createTree(String s) {
        return createTree(new Expression(s));
    }

    private static <T> Node<T> createTree(Expression expression) {
        Stack<Node<T>> nodeStack = new Stack<>();
        Stack<Token<T>> tokenStack = new Stack<>();

        Token<T> token = getNextToken(expression);

        while (token != null) {
            if (token instanceof OpenParenthesis) {
                tokenStack.push(token);
            } else if (token instanceof Element) {
                nodeStack.push(getNodeFromElement((Element) token));
            } else if (token instanceof EmptyElement) {
                nodeStack.push(null);
            } else if (token instanceof CloseParenthesis) {
                if (nodeStack.size() == 1) {
                    if (tokenStack.size() != 1) {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("When a CloseParenthesis is encountered " +
                                "and there is only one Node viz. the root Node in the nodeStack, " +
                                "there should be only 1 OpenParenthesis in the tokenStack.");
                    }
                    tokenStack.pop();
                    return nodeStack.pop();
                }

                tokenStack.pop();
                Node<T> right = nodeStack.pop();
                Node<T> left = nodeStack.pop();
                Node<T> node = nodeStack.pop();
                node.left = left;
                node.right = right;
                nodeStack.push(node);
            }

            token = getNextToken(expression);
        }

        return null;
    }

    private static <T> Node<T> getNodeFromElement(Element<T> token) {
        return new Node<>(token.getValue());
    }

    private static <T> Token<T> getNextToken(Expression expression) {
        String s = expression.s;
        Token<T> token = null;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < s.length() && s.charAt(i) == ' ') i++;

        if (i != s.length()) {
            if (s.charAt(i) == '(') {
                while (s.charAt(i) == ' ' && i < s.length()) i++;
                if (s.charAt(i + 1) == ')') {
                    token = new EmptyElement<T>();
                    i++;
                } else {
                    token = new OpenParenthesis<T>();
                }

                i++;
            } else if (s.charAt(i) == ')') {
                i++;
                token = new CloseParenthesis<>();
            } else if (s.charAt(i) >= '0' && s.charAt(i) <= '9') {
                int value = 0;
                while (s.charAt(i) >= '0' && s.charAt(i) <= '9' && i < s.length()) {
                    value = value * 10 + s.charAt(i) - '0';
                    i++;
                }
                token = new Element<>(value);
            } else {
                token = new Element<>("Trees with string instead of integers should be resolved here.");
            }
        }
        expression.s = s.substring(i);

        return token;
    }

    private static class Expression {
        String s;

        Expression(String s) {
            this.s = s;
        }
    }

    private static abstract class Token<T> { }

    private static class OpenParenthesis<T> extends Token { }

    private static class CloseParenthesis<T> extends Token { }

    private static class EmptyElement<T> extends Token { }

    private static class Element<T> extends Token {
        T value;

        Element(T value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public T getValue() {
            return value;
        }
    }

}
```

My input files look like this:

- tree1.txt - `(1 (2 (3 (10 11) 15) 4 (5 (() 13) 6)))`
- tree2.txt - `(1 (2 (3 (10 11) 15) 4 (5 6)))`
- tree3.txt - `(1(()()))`

---

#### Project Structure

I have created a `gradle` project. The project structure is as follows -

- The source files are under `src/main/java/org/yadavvi/util`
- The test files are under `src/test/java/org/yadavvi/util`
- the input resources (files `tree1.txt`, `tree2.txt` and `tree3.txt`)  are under `src/test/resources/org/yadavvi/util`

---

The test file `ReadTreeTest.java` (which is under `src/test/java/org/yadavvi/util`) looks like this -

```
package org.yadavvi.util;

import junitparams.JUnitParamsRunner;
import junitparams.Parameters;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import static org.yadavvi.util.TreeUtil.createTreeFromFile;

@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
public class ReadTreeTest {

    public Object[] filesForTrees() {
        return new Object[]{
                new Object[]{"tree1.txt"},
                new Object[]{"tree2.txt"},
                new Object[]{"tree3.txt"}
        };
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

    }

    @Test
    @Parameters(method = "filesForTrees")
    public void createTreeTest(String resourceName) throws Exception {
         createTreeFromFile(fileName);
    }
}
```

The project `gradle` file - `build.gradle` - looks like this -

```
group 'org.yadavvi'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'org.hamcrest', name: 'hamcrest-junit', version: '2.0.0.0'
    testCompile group: 'pl.pragmatists', name: 'JUnitParams', version: '1.0.6'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

---

Things I want feedbacks about:

- I have used `createTree()` using generics, however, I am getting a lot of typecast warnings.
- The logic of getting `Token`s is pretty bad.

Comment: How do you run this? What's the entry point?

Comment: @TamasRev I have edited the question to add a details about running the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the typecast warnings can be eliminated if you specify the `Token` -s type at the subclasses too:

```
private static class OpenParenthesis<T> extends Token<T> { }
```

So the compiler knows that an `OpenParenthesis<String>` is a subclass of `Token<String>`. Also, an `OpenParenthesis<String>` is not a subclass of `Token<Integer>`.

You can get rid of the other typecast warning at line 39 if you specify the the generic type of `element`:

```
nodeStack.push(getNodeFromElement((Element<T>) token));
```

There were two more warnings in `getNextToken`. The warning basically said that you could use the diamond syntax for the new `EmptyElement` and `OpenParentheses`. I.e. replace this:

```
token = new EmptyElement<T>();
...
token = new OpenParenthesis<T>();
```

with this:

```
token = new EmptyElement<>();
...
token = new OpenParenthesis<>();
```

Now we don't have too many warnings. However, there are two compile-time errors:

```
            int value = 0;
            // here is a compile-time error
            token = new Element<>(value);
        } else {
            // here is a compile-time error too
            token = new Element<>("Trees with string instead of integers should be resolved here.");
```

The problem is that you want to create an `Element<T>` either from `Integer` or from `String`. This is impossible because they don't belong to the same object tree - other than the general `Object` itself.

So you can do some casting and hope everything will be allright:

```
    Integer value = 0; // Integer for casting
    //
    token = new Element<>((T) value); // casting the value
} else {
    token = new Element<>((T) "Trees with string instead of integers should be resolved here."); // casting the value
}
```

However, I'd rather use `String`-s only and cast the values at a later step.

Other suggestions:

Some classes, like `OpenParenthesis` or `EmptyElement` do nothing. I suggest to use an `enum` instead.

Try to use less static methods.

The `createTree` method returns `null` no matter what. I'd move the stack-to-tree logic into a separate method and I'd invoke that here.

Comment: `Integer value = 0; token = new Element<T>((T) value);` gives compilation error even after making `private static class Element<T> extends Token<T>` instead of `private static class Element<T> extends Token`.

Comment: On the one hand, it's my bad. It's enough to write `new Element<>((T) value);`. On the other hand it does **not** give compilation error. It gives a warning: *Unchecked cast from Integer to T*. Did you change the signature of `getNextToken()` ?

Comment: It worked with using `Integer value;` instead of `int value`, I'm sorry. Can you explain what the difference between `private static class Element<T> extends Token<T>` and `private static class Element<T> extends Token` is ?

Comment: If you write `private static class Element<T> extends Token<T>` then you make sure that the `Element` class uses the same type as `Token` does. I.e. `Element<Integer> element = new Element<>();` will set the type token of `Element` and `Token` to `Integer`. On the other hand, if you write `private static class Element<T> extends Token<T>`, then `Element<Integer> element = new Element<>();` will specify the `Element` type as `Integer`, however, `Token` -s type remains unspecified.

Comment: Did you mean - "On the other hand, if you write `private static class Element<T> extends Token`, then `Element<Integer> element = new Element<>();` will specify the `Element` type as `Integer`, however, `Token` -s type remains unspecified."  instead of what you've written?

Comment: Oh, yes :) Thanks! In the second case the `extends Token` part has no type definition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58575/discussion-between-tamas-rev-and-yadav-vi).